# How to create id for each spring jpa composite key group?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I want to increase the id value in this way according to sample_id: 1, 2, 3.. 1, 2, 3.. How to do it?
You can think of the id value increasing by 1 for each group.

```
@Entity
@IdClass(CompositeKey.class)
public class EntityExample {
    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "sample_id")
    private SampleEntity sample;

    @Id
    private Long id;

    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: So you want to set the `id` value equal to `sample_id`?

Comment: The simplest solution would be, of course, to handle this on the application side. If what you want is for the samples to be indexed, then perhaps `@OrderColumn` on the `@OneToMany` side is what you want.  Finally, you could try [implementing a custom id generator](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://thorben-janssen.com/custom-sequence-based-idgenerator/&ved=2ahUKEwiEqcvcgdrvAhWRmIsKHbtyBG8QFjABegQIKhAC&usg=AOvVaw2OzfwOAdX0W4T-cCLLS82-)

Comment: I solved it by implementing the id generator separately. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by implementing the id generator separately. Thank you.

```
public class CompositeKeyGenerator extends IdentityGenerator {

  @Override
  public Serializable generate(SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object obj) throws HibernateException {
    if (obj instanceof EntityExample) {
      String query = String.format("select id from %s where sample.id = %d",
          obj.getClass().getSimpleName(), ((EntityExample) obj).getSampleEntity().getSampleId());

      List<Long> resultList = session.createQuery(query).getResultList();
      if (!resultList.isEmpty()) {
        return resultList.stream().mapToLong(v -> v).max().orElse(1L) + 1;
      }
      return 1L;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```